# MySQL Month Datetime Max Count

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to find the maxcount of a datetime row.

That is, I am trying to display the name of the most frequently occurring month in a column of DATETIME information.

here is my code:

```
Select MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit) as Monat
From abflug a
group by MONTH(a.AF_Zeit)
having count(AF_Zeit) = (select max(count(MONTH(AF_Zeit)))
                from abflug
                group by MONTH(AF_Zeit))
```

mySQL returns the message:"#1111 - Invalid use of group function"

I don't get it!
I heard there where other possibilities to get this, but i kinda have to do it with subselects.
I'm very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to display the name of the most frequently occurring month in your AF_ZEIT column of your ABFLUG table.

How do you do this? Let us work through it conceptually.

First you need a virtual table (a subselect as you put it) showing the month name for each row of your ABFLUG table.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit) as Monat
  FROM ABFLUG A
```

Then you need to count these items (or, you could say, get a histogram by month).  This will do that. It's a smaller virtual table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NNN, MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit) as Monat
  FROM ABFLUG A
 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit)
```

Then you need to manipulate the rows of that table to order them in descending order frequency, and display the first (most frequent) one.

```
SELECT Z.Monat FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) NNN, MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit) as Monat
    FROM ABFLUG A
   GROUP BY MONTHNAME(a.AF_Zeit) 
  )Z
  ORDER BY Z.NNN
  LIMIT 1
```

Note that the hard part of this is achieving conceptual clarity on what you're trying to do in the parlance of virtual tables.